# uitableview doesn't prints row index value for every clicks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using the following code to get the index of tablecell that got clicked.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];

    NSLog(@"you have selected %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it prints the index value of row only once. If I tap the tableviews anymore, it doesn't print the index value. How to know which index I have clicked ?

Comment: Are you saying that you pop back and then the table view no long recognizes row selections?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
     NSLog(@"you have selected %d",indexPath.row);
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
    tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: still it doesn't work.It doesn't provide index value for multitouch

Comment: if yiu want in multi touch u need to implement in gesture on cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell * tableCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isSelected = (tableCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);
    if (isSelected)
    {
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
    else
    {
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Now check when accessory check marks appears it will print the index path  or not??

Comment: thank you, im trying to get the index value of selected table cell using `NSLog(@"%@",tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow);` but it prints null value

Comment: nslog (@"%@", indexpath.row);

Comment: it will give you the value on which row you selected. @Stanly